# retrofit 2 make request compilated but throws sockettimeoutexception

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm facing the strangest issue here.
I am using retrofit for making requests but I'm getting socket timeout exception
at first i thought it's back end problem but it's working on post man.
and then when we checked out back end log we realized the request will be compilated and gives 200 code but I'm not getting any response!!!!!

here is my code

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

and here is my code init retrofit

```
private static Retrofit cRetrofit = null;
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

public static final int CACHE_EX_TIME = 60;
public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    httpClient.connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Comment: Check if you have provided internet permission.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @SreedevPR I have this permission